# How can I superpose an md-dialog on md-dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I tried to open a md-dialog from an opened one ,but the problem is that the first md-dialog closed when the second opened

```
// the controller of the first popUp 
class popUpOneController{
      constructor($mdDialog){
      this.$mdDialog=$mdDialog;
       .
       .
       .
       } 
  others methods codes......
// the second $mdDialog to be opened from the  first 
// this function will be executed by clicking  on a html  button
  openPopUp2(){
      // here we call a component into the $mdDialog
      this.$mdDialog.show({
            template: '<interlo-sibel  data-to-pass='+data+'  index-selectedElm='+index+' type='+type+' ></interlo-sibel>',
            targetEvent: event,
            escapeToClose: false

        })
   } 
   popUpOneController.$inject=['$mdDialog'];


 export default popUpOneController
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer , we have just add the following attiribute 'skipHide: true'

```
 openPopUp2(){
      // here we call a component into the $mdDialog
      this.$mdDialog.show({
            template: '<interlo-sibel  data-to-pass='+data+'  index-selectedElm='+index+' type='+type+' ></interlo-sibel>',
            targetEvent: event,
            skipHide: true


        })
   }
```

the demo link on plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/jaDD79A1JII4XKhXP64Y?p=preview